# Not able to use XUnit for unit tests in ASP.NET VNext and Visual Studio 2015 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a a Visual Studio 2015 RC solution as follows:

```
Project
  global.json
Source
  MvcProject
  MvcProject.Test
```

MvcProject.Test is a class library where I created a Test.

The global.json file has the following:

```
{
  "projects": [ "Source" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta4"
  }
}
```

And project.json in MvcProject.Test is:

```
{
  "compilationOptions": {
    "warningsAsErrors": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
    "xunit.runner.aspnet": "2.0.0-aspnet-*"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.aspnet"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Moq": "4.2.1506.2016"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then created a simple test:

```
using Xunit;

namespace MvcProject.Test {
  public class FirstTests {

    [Fact]
    public void HelloTest() {
      Assert.Equal(2, 2);
    }

  }
}
```

When I build the solition I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Fact' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  MvcProject.Test.DNX 4.5.1   

The name 'Assert' does not exist in the current context Bityond.Test.DNX 4.5.1
```

What am I missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 2):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/08/06/unit-testing-with-dnx-asp-net-5-projects.aspx) works with RTM. Please leave comments on the blog if you have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide for it here I followed it and works perfectly.

http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with Release Version of Visual Studio 2015, but it looks like with enough smarts, and persistence one could figure out what's wrong and fix it.

Comment: I'll have a look haven't been working on my vnext project recently so didn't notice.

Comment: I encountered problems where neither the console dnx runner, nor the visualstudio runner works anymore. `"commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"  }` for example, does not provide IDE integration, and doesn't run from the commandline

Comment: I figured it out and made a demo that works.

https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/aspnet5mvc6xunitdemo