# What is the new Class Library (Package) in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I've been trying to do a sample 3-tier app with PL, BLL, and DAL and now I'm doing some unit tests. I was about to reference the BLL to my test project but then suddenly it won't allow it. I found out that this class library is different from the regular class library.

So, right now, I don't know if I should replace this with the regular class library or continue using the new one (package). What is appropriate for this situation? Lets say this 3-tier program is a cloud app.

Or maybe the right questions are:

1. What's the difference between the old class library and this new one?
2. When is one appropriate? I can't find clear answers googling around.
3. Can you do unit testing with the new one using current MS Test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going asp.net-core you I would suggest to stick with the newer Class Library (Package), unless you have reason to use that same library in other projects that does not use DNX to compile/execute.

1. `Class Library (.csproj)` and `Class Library Package (.kproj)`. The big difference between these two types of projects is that the Class Library (Package) will use the file `project.json` and DNX to compile, execute and package the library, where as the standard Class Library (.csproj) uses .net framework to compile and execute the library .dll file.

   *Side note: The package project (.kproj) will create a NuGet package automatically (where as the Class Library (.csproj) you would have to build your NuGet package manually).*
2. The main thing you need to know is that you can reference a `Class Library (.csproj)` in a `Class Library (Package) (.kproj)` and not the other way around,  because of DNX. So this means all the unit test libraries wont work with asp.net core at the moment. A good way to get around that is to use `XUnit` in a `Class Library (Project) (.kproj)`. If this library is shared between other projects that does not support DNX (eg between an older MVC5 project and a new ASP.NET Core project), you cant use a Class Library Package `.kproj` and would have to go with the standard Class Library `.csproj` project.
3. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751864/1284637 how to get unit testing working with asp.net core. As answered in 2, app.net-core does not currently support unit test libraries, that means MSTest will also not work.

I hope this helps clear things up for you.

Answer (score 2):

1 and 2 have been answered perfectly by Nick De Beer (my compliments @Nick De Beer).

But as far as 3 is concerned, as of december 2015 there is a NuGet package called MSTest.Runner.Dnx which targets DNX especially for MSTest. You can read here how to set it up in a DNX project: https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2016/03/07/asp-net-core-1-0s-dnx-and-mstest/